# NSDate from string wrong conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD"];
NSDate *offsetDay = [dateFormatter dateFromString:entry.date];
```

String entry.date is 2014-02-16 and resulting offsetDay is 2014-01-16.
Why is this happening??

Thanks.

Comment: Did you NSLog to make sure `entry.date` is really `2014-02-16`

Comment: Yeah... I would understand that its something wrong with "day" because of some offset but whole "month"???

Comment: yyyy-MM-DD change it to yyyy-MM-dd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

If I remember correctly, `DD` is day of the year, not day of the month like you want. You can find a complete `NSDateFormatter` formatting table [here](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/)

Comment: Yeah, that solved it... Have to wait 9 more min for accept... Thanks a lot, classic typing mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

try this code edit.

```
 NSString *entry=@"2014-01-16";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *offsetDay = [dateFormatter dateFromString:entry];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

NSLog(@"date--%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:offsetDay]);
```